# NoSuchMethodError: buildSessionFactory using Hibernate 5.1.0 and c3p0

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to run a hibernate application on tomcat 7.0.57 using c3p0 connection pool management. It is not possible to build a sessionFactory due to a NoSuchMethodError.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">180</property>
```

When I'm restarting the Tomcat I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.extractIsolation(Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:200)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
at urlarchiv.db.HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:27)
at urlarchiv.db.UrlManager.<init>(UrlManager.java:18)
at urlarchiv.reader.XmlReader.readXml(XmlReader.java:99)
at urlarchiv.reader.XmlReader.readXml(XmlReader.java:80)
at urlarchiv.servlets.UrlArchivingServlet.init(UrlArchivingServlet.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The exception is thrown here (buildSessionFactory):

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    try {
        configuration.configure();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        configuration.configure("/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    }

    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

EDIT:
My maven dependency tree

```
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.11:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
```

Comment: do you have an earlier version of Hibernate - particularly hibernate-core - somewhere on the classpath by any chance? perhaps pre-deployed to the Tomcat container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like kem already asked, there really was still an earlier hibernate version (4.3.6.) deployed to the tomcat container, which caused that exception. This version was used in another jar within the same webapp.

Updating this jar to the same version solved the problem.